# IQueryable Parent-Child

Tags: linq-to-sql

I need to cast: `IQueryable<PARENT>` to `IQueryable<Child>`.

```
IQueryable<PARENT> query = GetParents();

IQueryable<CHILD> result = query.Select(t => t.Children);
```

This doesn't work, unable to convert EntitySet to IQueryable. Thanks

Comment: When you mean cast this implies that you can cast `Parent` to `Child`, i.e. that Parent inherits from child, or that both implement the same interface, although that contradicts IQueryable<CHILD>.

Comment: Yes, they have entityset association in a database, so child inherits from parent. Your method works, but creates some duplicates for some reason.

Comment: Modified my answer. However, he relationship you are describing is a 1:n relationship. I.e. Parent has multiple Childs and each child has a parent. Inheritance is different! It describes an of type relation ship, e.g. Cucumber is of type Vegetable. When you are getting duplicates it means that (in case of a 1:n) relationship you have multiple entries with the same values in your child table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
IQueryable<CHILD> result = query.SelectMany(t => t.Children);
```

The query returns all cild items of the parent, childs referenced by multiple parents will be returned multiple times.

To get the distinct rows use - you will have to implement a class that Implements IComparer though, to do a custom filtering. `Distinct()` will look at the instances and not the values.

```
IQueryable<CHILD> result = query.SelectMany(t => t.Children)
                                .Distict(new Comparer<CHILD>());
```

`Distinct()` removes duplicats from the query.

Aternatively you can use grouping to create a grouping for the children:

```
IEnumerable<CHILD> result = query.SelectMany(t => t.Children)
                                 .GroupBy(x => new CHILD { 
                                      id = x.id 
                                      // add other properties here
                                 })
                                 .Select(g => g.Key);
```

Instead of `new CHILD { }` you could also use `new { }` to create an anonymous result, in this case you should replace `IEnumerable<CHILD>` with `var`.

To perform a type cast in Linq you can use - **although I would assume that this will not work in you case**:

```
someQuery.OfType<TypeToCastTo>().Cast<TypeToCastTo>();
```

`OfType<T>()` filters the items so that `Cast<T>()` can perform the type cast.